# Google+ pictures becoming corrupt

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos

Recently, I was browsing through my Google+ photos on my Android phone and I noticed that many of them appear to have been corrupted. They are covered in varying patterns of colored bars. I've noticed that the exact same pictures are also corrupt on the web interface of Google+, and when downloading photos on desktop and mobile. Disturbingly, the corruption appears to be retroactive - photos going back to 2012 are now corrupt. All photos appeared to upload correctly originally, but then the corruption happened sometime in early 2014.

My phone is a Verizon Galaxy SIII, stock Android 4.3, using auto backup with Google+. I've attached a screenshot of the Google+ web interface showing some of the corrupted photos.

Is there any way to recover affected photos and to prevent this issue from recurring?

[image: corrupt images on Google+ web interface]

Comment: And if you download them on your desktop they appear corrupt as well?

Comment: @Alex yes, they do appear corrupt when downloading on desktop

Comment: Edited question with that and other relevant info

Comment: It's a long shot, but have you tried contacting Google about this? Seems like a pretty serious bug on their part. Sorry about your photos.

Comment: Are you able to select and view the files without problems or the main files are corrupt also?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Google+ was retired several years ago. It doesn't make sense that this question still be shown on the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score -2):

#### IMPORTANT  Google+ is shutting down on April 2.  All your data will vanish.

Download all your pix, corrupt or not and save locally.

Announcement here: https://support.google.com/plus/answer/9195133?hl=en

Meanwhile...

Not quite a web-apps answer, but leaning more to a superuser answer.

https://www.jihosoft.com/free-utilities/jpeg-repair-tool.html

lists several apps that claim to repair jpeg images.  As with all data recovery, it's a bit of a crap shoot.

You can find more with a google search 'corrupt jpeg recovery'

**Note:**  Free software is often worth what you pay for it, and may be a vehicle to put malware on your computer.  In general I suggest that you download a virtual machine, either a pre-made one, or download virtual-box and install an OS on it.  Either lock that VM or make a copy, install the software, and test it out.  After, revert your VM to it's previous state or discard the copy.

Comment: The Google+ photos feature was long ago migrated over to Google drive, and all my photos (including the corrupted ones) live on there.

Comment: Yes, but your headline reads, "Google+" And therefore this note may help other people looking for Google+ who aren't aware of the change.  MY photos on Google+ have not migrated.  I have other uses for my google drive.